# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple MVC application in which i want to show location dynamically from Google map.

I am getting this Error in this file----

**Unhandled exception** at line 16, column 59007 in              https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'

The View page contains simple html with javaScript code and some javaScript files included----

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <link  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Google Maps </h1>
    <div align="left">
    <input type="text" value="" id="searchbox" style="  width:800px;height:30px; font-size:10px; margin-top: 7px;">
    </div>
    <div align="left" id="map" style="width:800px; height: 600px; margin-top: 10px;">

   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

     var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.06000, 28.98700)
             };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    $(function () {
        $("#searchbox").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {

                if (geocoder == null) {
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                }
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        var searchLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                        var bounds = results[0].geometry.bounds;

                        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results1, status1) {
                            if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results1[1]) {
                                    response($.map(results1, function (loc) {
                                        return {
                                            label: loc.formatted_address,
                                            value: loc.formatted_address,
                                            bounds: loc.geometry.bounds
                                        }
                                    }));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var pos = ui.item.position;
                var lct = ui.item.locType;
                var bounds = ui.item.bounds;

                if (bounds) {
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot see that you're using getElementsByTagName in your code.

Comment: your code works fine for me, without any error

Comment: I am getting the error at run time when i load the page for the first time from visual studio---

Comment: I am getting the error at run time when i load the page for the first time from visual studio--- It opens the popUp window with the errors stated above in my asp.net mvc application with three options--                             1>Break ,2>Continue, 3>Cancel                                                                    If i click continue then it ignore the error and loads the full page with google map in it.....Is there something to do with Js files included in Scripts folder  their versions is something like jquery-2.1.4.js.....Any help Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to answer my own question...................I think those old javaScript library file were not compatible with the new versions of IE9. So, I just changed the referenced js libraries files to latest one from this page....developers.google.com/speed/libraries and everything is working fine now....

Answer (score 0):

you can include jquery migrate js file in your project to resolve this. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js

Answer (score 0):

I wish I can put this as a comment but I dont have enough reps...

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Show'

The error above led me to this question and when I didn't find my answer, I looked at it again and the answer was much simpler - I miss-typed 'show' as 'Show'.

> $('#Member').closest('.form-group').Show();

I changed it back to lowercase 's'- .show() - I hope this alerts someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I **add letest version of jquery** and solved problem...

Like....**"jquery-1.10.2.js"**
.
..